# How do apply multiple if statements?

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I have a df, and want to apply the following statement for each row;

```
IF df['aon'] == 12, recode to 10,  but also change on the same row df['identity'] == 4 and df['NO'] == 2.5 df['HR'] == 110

ELSEIF df['aon'] == 10, recode to 8 .
```

If these conditions are not met I want to leave each row untouched. I know a way to do this, but I'd like the most effective way if possible.

Before;

```
Aon    Identity    No    HR

11     8.0         3.5   99
12     7.0         3.1   99
21     8.0         2.8   100
12     7.0         1.5   78
31     4.0         1.2   95
```

After;

```
Aon    Identity    No    HR

11     8.0         3.5   99
12     4.0         2.5   110
21     8.0         2.8   100
12     4.0         2.5   110
31     4.0         1.2   95
```

Comment: Could you clarify "the most effective way"? Are you looking for the fastest way? The most readable code? Also, I might be missing something, but I'm not sure I understand your description. I think you mean "set" rather than "change" and `=` rather than `==` in some places. Finally, can you show how the data is actually stored - in Python code?

Comment: So most effective meaning as much code within a single equals sign, it's a dataframe. I just want to turn the 'before' df into the 'After' df

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Since you have no input data with `Aon` equal `10` - I took `21` as an example, since it exists.

```py
>>> df
   Aon  Identity   No   HR
0   11       8.0  3.5   99
1   12       7.0  3.1   99
2   21       8.0  2.8  100
3   12       7.0  1.5   78
4   31       4.0  1.2   95
>>> df.apply(lambda x: {"Aon": 10, "Identity": 4, "No": 2.5, "HR": 110} if x["Aon"]==12 else ({"Aon": 8, "Identity": x.Identity, "No": x.No, "HR": x.HR} if x["Aon"]==21 else x), axis=1)
    Aon     HR  Identity   No
0  11.0   99.0       8.0  3.5
1  10.0  110.0       4.0  2.5
2   8.0  100.0       8.0  2.8
3  10.0  110.0       4.0  2.5
4  31.0   95.0       4.0  1.2
```

Answer (score 1):

you question is not clear on exactly what condition you want but
you can use combination of logical operation and pandas where function to achive what you want

for example if you want to select rows matching following condition 
df['identity'] == 4 and df['NO'] == 2.5 df['HR'] == 110 you can do

```py
cond = (df['identity'] == 4) & (df['NO'] == 2.5) & (df['HR'] == 110)

## then you can use the above condition to set value on col1 like this
## this will set 10 to rows not matching the cond
df["col1"] = df["col1"].where(cond, 10)


## this will set 10 to rows matching the cond
df["col1"] = df["col1"].mask(cond, 10)
```